# Word 2010 cross-reference number with chapter without label

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, cross-reference

I have the following problem. First I had images and other elements labeled just by number, so from 1 to ∞. When I cross referenced I changed to number only using the following:

```
{ REF _Ref334952863 \# 0 \h }
```

And it worked fine, I got only the image number. Then I found new instructions, saying I have to change captions to `paragraph.number`, like so:

[image]

But my referencing now is completely broken, all I get is number `4`. What I need is `2.2`, so number without the label. If I leave label it works, I can get Slika 2.2, but I can't use the label.

The reason is, unlike English, my language uses declination, and I cannot use "slika" everywhere, sometimes it's "slike" or "sliki" and sometimes I just want to use number in brackets only [2.2].

Answer (score 7):

The workaround with # 0.0 or # 0 in the answer above work only for one-digit numberings. (according to http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/how-to-disply-figure-number-only-in-cross/02ae3cd0-6c3c-401d-990c-5220d7f0be1e).

But you can use the "kludgy workaround": http://wordfaqs.mvps.org/CombineXrefs.htm

In short, 10 simple steps:

1. Use classic "Add cross reference" to `Slika 2.2`
2. Press Shift+F9 to show field code. You shoud see something like `{ REF _Ref107244825 }` instead of `Slika 2.2`.
3. Select and copy the `_Ref107244825` part.
4. Press Shift+F9 again.
5. Go to the caption of `Slika 2.2` (e.g. by Ctrl+click on the inserted reference)
6. Select the `2.2` part of the caption
7. Open the "Insert bookmark" dialog
8. In the dialog, check the "Show hidden bookmarks" checkbox
9. Find the `_Ref107244825` (you can e.g. paste the copied text from step 3)
10. Click "Add" and then close the dialog

Now, when you actualize the fields (e.g. press F9), the reference becomes `2.2` and you can add declined "Na slike".

Comment: "\# 0" works for multiple digits. You can also use "\* arabic". But I don't know about chapter numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `\# 0`, try adding `\# 0.0`. That way, you would only get the `paragraph.number` format (so, the actuall hyperlink would only include the "2.2" part, and you would add the "slika" part as plain text in front).

If you would like to add some text inside the hyperlink (so a wider area than 3-4 characters is clickable), I suggest adding it as custom text, enclosed in single-quotes:

```
{ REF _Ref334952863 \# "'na slici' 0.0" \h }
```

So, the example you mentioned would look like this:

```
{ REF _Ref334952863 \# "'['0.0']'" \h }
```

P.S. Don't forget that if you want to add multiple things to the `\#` declaration, you have to enclose them in double-quotes.

---

Sources:

- http://wordfaqs.mvps.org/combinexrefs.htm
- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-and-format-field-codes-in-word-2007-HA010338798.aspx

Comment: I only get 01, 02, the first number is always 0

Comment: Well, are you sure you "told" word that you've started a new chapter by using the apropriate style? By default, this is "Heading 1".  
  
All figures inserted before the begining of the first chapter would be labeled with a leading zero.

Comment: It just doesn't work. All i get is [01],[02]. I can get the dot by putting it into single quote. I used heading 1 and there was no effect

Comment: Have you found the solution yet?

Comment: I’ve seen this solution in several places on the web.  Either it does not work at all and everybody copies it without checking, or it only works in English.  (There’s a decimal point involved, so I wouldn’t put it past Microsoft to mess this up.)

Comment: By now, I have confirmed that this approach does not work in German versions, so probably in any locale that doesn’t use a decimal *point*.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a little workaround for this problem. It's not the neatest solution but it works if you need this feature desperately. It works with figures, tables, whatever. What i do is:

Suppose i have a figure followed by the figure title which is something like:
Figure 5.23 Effect of temperature on parameter Z

I create a 2-columned, single row table where i
- type "Figure" on the leftmost cell 
- insert the caption (in this case 5.23) followed by the title text in the right cell

Then i just put the table really close to my figure so that i don't end up with an ugly gap between the figure and the figure title.

Essentially, this separates the word "Figure" from the caption so you can type whatever you want before your cross-references. The only downside is that if you create a Table of Figures, you will have to type the word "Figure" to the left of the figure reference number by hand for every single figure but that's not a deal breaker in my opinion. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your question is similar to the below case study

Case study: Your publisher requests to move all figures and tables to other files and at these places say "Insert Figure..." or "Insert Table".
The problem is when referring them in the text, they will appear all "Insert figure..." or "Insert table..", not showing only the number of the figures or tables.

Problem-solving:
Select "Insert figure.." in the text, display menu Home, open Font, and check Hidden text.
Voila, there are only numbers of figures or tables. Then you can type any text you want before the number

Trick:
Use Macro with those steps above, assign keyboard shortcuts
Use Finding with the keyword to jump to exactly the text you want to run the macro

https://sites.google.com/site/tnncuong/home/trouble-shooting/showonlynumberincross-referenceinword2007document#

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation when I used the Numeric format switch. Somehow the word would convert all the numbers in the caption into a summation.

A trick you can play here to get the figure number correct is substracting the chapter number in your field code. Here is an example to get `2.x`.

-> type the chapter number yourself, like `2.`

-> Click 'Insert-Quick Parts-Field...'

-> Choose 'Formula'

-> Enter `=x-m` in Formula, `x` is a random number, `m` is the chapter number, hit OK

-> The field code would be `{=x-m }`

-> Replace `x` by inserting the cross-reference of Figure m-n;

-> Select Figure m-n in the field and choose 'Toggle Field Codes';

-> Revise it to be

```
  {REF _Ref73436767 \# 0 \h}
```

the whole field code would be

```
 {={REF _Ref73436767 \# 0 \h}-m }
```

-> Choose 'Toggle Field Codes' and F9, you would get the correct number for `x` and hyperlink at the same time! You can get `2.x` in the text with the x being updated.

Hope this can help.

Comment: In an answer, you should tell the person what to do, at least in outline form. You have simply provided a link.