# Cross Refence Appendix without Label

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, field-codes, cross-reference

I have a document with a lot of appendixes, normally I cross reference the appendix just like any paragraph number and it brings in the entire label, for example "Appendix A." Now in my document I would like to say "See Appendixes B-G" where the B and G are cross referenced, but I can not figure out how to link only to the letters without the label.

For figures and tables I use the "kludgy workaround" shown here [Word 2010 cross-reference number with chapter without label](https://superuser.com/questions/474503/word-2010-cross-reference-number-with-chapter-without-label). But I can not use this method on Appendixes because when I attempt to select just the letter it selects the entire label as well. This is because the appendix style format I use includes a number format the includes the "Appendix" label, so the label is part of the sequential number.

I also tried deleting the number format and creating the numbering using a field codes, i.e. `{ SEQ Appendix \* ALPHABETIC }`. This worked great for the Appendix labels themselves, but they no longer showed up in the cross-reference selection tool. I also couldn't get field code references to work, even when I created a bookmark, but I also couldn't find a good example.

So does anyone know how I can get a cross reference to link to an Appendix, without using the "Appendix" label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a \t switch into the cross-reference's REF field to remove the "Appendix " part of the label.

(Sorry, I had forgotten about that). I have left the other two approaches below just in case they are applicable to some other variation on this problem.

One way, although you still can't use the cross-reference selection tool, and you will typically lose other Word crossref/tables/index features as well, is to do this:

Use

```
Appendix { SEQ App \*Alphabetic }"
```

to insert each Appendix label, as you have already tried.

Bookmark each Appendix label that you need to reference (it is only necessary that you bookmark the { SEQ } field).

So e.g. bookmark Appendix labels A-G as Violet, Indigo, Blue, Green, Yellow, Orange, Red.

Define your reference as

```
Appendixes { SEQ App Indigo \*Alphabetic }-{ SEQ App Red \*Alphabetic }
```

I am not convinced that it is actually any more maintainable to do this than to insert the cross-reference completely manually and maintain it manually. For example, if you reduce the range (so it's B-F), then you either have to re-bookmark F as "Red" or you have to change the second SEQ to { SEQ App Orange *Alphabetic }. This is a general problem with cross-referencing but it seems to me to get worse when you move away from the familiarity of the built-in mechanisms.

There is another approach that might just about work as long as everyone working on the document knows what is going on. It assumes LISTNUM is reliable (it seems to be a bit quirky):

Use multilist numbering to apply the full "Appendix A" label. Assume that you use Level 1 for that number.

Set up Level 9 (say) so that it consists of the *number* from Level 1 (using the "Include level number from" dropdown) and nothing else. Format the "number" as A,B,C...

At the beginning of each Appendix that you need to cross-reference, insert the following field

```
{ LISTNUM \l 9 }
```

This *should* display the same letter as is in the Appendix label.

Select the LISTNUM field, and insert a bookmark - e.g. use Violet...Red for A-G as before.

Format the Field/result as Hidden

Define your reference as

```
Appendixes { Indigo \*Charformat }-{ Red \*Charformat }
```

Now we're back to using Ref fields you may also be able to use other things such as \h.

Ideally, it would be possible to set the bookmark and hide the result of the LISTNUM using

```
{ SET Indigo "{ LISTNUM \l 9 }" }
```

but the { LISTNUM } result appears to be blank whenever it is nested inside another field.

The *Charformat is there to "counteract" the Hidden formatting.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but I agree with you that it is probably easier in the long run to just do it manually the few times I need to, as opposed to doing all of this for every reference to the appendixes and the Headache getting the formatting right in the TOC.

Comment: @OSUZorba : From the point of view of document maintenance, it's probably more useful to insert markers that make it more easy for you to revisit manual cross-references that you might need to fix up. IMO one fairly easy way to do that is to insert a documentation field code such as { SET needsfixing (possibly followed by a note) }. There is no visible result, and nothing relies on the "needsfixing" bookmark that will move around depending on which SET field you last updated. But you can reveal the field codes and use Find/Replace to find "needsfixing" and do whatever is needed.

Comment: I have added a second approach that might be slightly more practical.

Comment: Aargh! Sorry, had forgotten about the \t switch