# Word 2013 Cross reference "Figure A" need to just show the A not Figure

Tags: microsoft-word

Inserting a cross reference to a Figure shows Figure A, Figure B, etc. However, if we want to put Figure A, B, C etc. with the B and C as the cross reference how do we alter the field code to remove the word Figure?

In numbered fields, e.g. Figure 1, Figure 2 etc. we can in put #0 before the reference to make it just show the number, but with letters this doesn't work, and can't seem to find what to input.
I.E.: "Part 1 and [Part] 2" is shown by altering the field code to Part 2 as follows:
From:
( Ref _Ref536659960 \h ) to ( Ref #0 _Ref536659960 \h )
the #0 removes the word Part, while still retaining the cross reference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related:  [How to show “only number” in picture cross-reference in Word 2007 document?](https://superuser.com/q/150952/150988)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware it is not possible to take out the label referencing a figure with lettered captions by editing the field code, just delete the label with <kbd>backspace</kbd> or <kbd>delete</kbd>

[image: Editing Cross-Reference with Backspace and Delete]

For References to Numbered Labels

Right click on the reference and click on <kbd>Toggle field codes</kbd>. When field codes are showing, edit the field code by inserting `\#0` as the *first* parameter after the reference number, so it should look like `{REF _REF36659960 \#0 \h}`. Once completed, right click on the reference again and click <kbd>Update field</kbd>.

Comment: Using your first solution of just deleting "Table" in my case, puts table back when I export in PDF

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a bodge but I was having the same trouble - you select the "Figure" you want to hide/delete and format the font as "Hidden". This will then not show up if you 'Update Field' or go to print/export - as it would do if you simply deleted it.

Hope this helps.

[image: Solution]

Comment: Word 365 does not allow me to select only "Table" in "Table 1". When I select "able", it allows me to do that. But when I select the "T", all the "Table 1" is selected, not just "Table"